# The size of the automorphism group of a graph

Tags: graph-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, symmetric-groups, graph-isomorphism

I am going through [QUANTUM MECHANICAL ALGORITHMS FOR THE
NONABELIAN HIDDEN SUBGROUP PROBLEM](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~vazirani/Papers/hidden.subgroup.pdf) by Grigni et a. It is said on page 14 that the size of the automorphism group of a graph is either $1$ or $2$. I assume the size of a group is the order of the group. Here is the screenshot.

[image]

Could anyone please explain why it is either  $1$ or $2$?

Comment: Since $Aut(K_n)=S_n$ so certainly all graphs do not have automorphism groups of size 1 or 2.

Comment: It doesn't say it's either 1 or 2. It says the general case can be done if you can do the special case where you happen to know that it's either 1 or 2.

Comment: So are we OK now?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, yes. Thanks.